# Django Rest Framework Seralize duration filed with custom datatype

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a model and that is with django `DurationField()`

```
class Elpased(models.Model):
    total_duration = models.DurationField(
        default=30
    )
```

and this is my serializer,

```
class ElapsedSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Elapsed
        fields = '__all__'
```

I am getting data in response ln this pattern:

it menas 2 minutes `"total_duration": "00:02:00",`
It means 25 second `"total_duration": "00:00:25",`

But I dont like this, I want to get the data in second, like if there `"total_duration": "00:02:00",` it should be like this `"total_duration": "120",`

if there is `"total_duration": "00:00:25",`, it should like this: `"total_duration": "25",`

Can anyone help to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Customize your field return:**

```
class ElapsedSerializer(ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Elapsed
    fields = '__all__'

  total_duration = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

  def get_total_duration(self, obj):
    total_duration = obj.total_duration
    h, m, s = total_duration.split(':')
    return int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + int(s)
```

Comment: @Showy, @pythonerdude in `ElapsedSerializer` class you should add field `total_duration`, which should be equal to `serializers.SerializerMethodField()` and it will work as expected